# How to Pass Header Value in Angular 7

Tags: angular, http, authentication, header, http-headers

I am trying to pass values via HTTP Headers
here is my code

```
this.ParamObj = {'companyId': this.TenandtID , 'groupId': this.SiteID , 
 'userId': this.userID, 'ticket': this.TangoToken, 'tangoApplicationName': 
  'BUI' };
   const two  = JSON.stringify(this.ParamObj);
  const headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.TangoToken)
  .set('Tango-Context', two);
 this.http.get(environment.GetTangoApps,   { responseType: 'text', headers: headers }).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

cant able to pass it 
in response, I get 403 and cross-origin error

Comment: You can't fix cross-origin (CORS) errors front-end..

Comment: so how do i fix this issue

Comment: Do a proper config. on server side

Comment: Quick hack, you can use [CORS Plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) for chrome.

Comment: this error show up => 

 has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.